# Snakemake : samples with sub-items, how catch them?

Tags: wildcard, snakemake

Here is a short example of a config.yaml :

```
samples:
  sample1:
    stranded: True
  sample2:
    stranded: False
```

As you see, each sample has a sub-item (multiples in fact). But I don't know how catch them.
My Snakefile :

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
  input:
    expand("output/{sample}.bam", sample=config['samples']),

rule one:
  input:
    "input/{sample}.bam",
  output:
    "output/{sample}.bam",
  run:
    if config['samples']["{sample}"]['stranded']: # How catch stranded value ?
      option = "--stranded",
    shell(
      'some_command '
      ' {option}'
      ' {input} > {output}'
    )
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Hetica

Answer (score 2):

finally, I found a response, using lambda function in params instruction, and a condition in run:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule all:
  input:
    expand("output/{sample}.bam", sample=config['samples']),

rule one:
  input:
    "input/{sample}.bam",
  output:
    "output/{sample}.bam",
  params:
    stranded = lambda wildcards: config['samples'][wildcards.sample]['stranded'],
  run:
    stranded = "--stranded" if params.stranded else ''
    shell(
        'echo '
        + stranded +
        ' {input} > {output};\n'
        'touch {output}'
    )
```

If this can helps someone...